# Gtk - How to set box size?

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm3

I have the following window on my project:

[image]

And this is basically the code that configure the main boxes:

```
add(main_box);
// Add boxes
main_box.pack_start(function_box, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK, 10);
main_box.pack_start(viewport_box);
```

I would to like to expand the `viewport_box` to ocupe a width larger than the half of the window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can either change PACK_SHRINK to [PACK_EXPAND_WIDGET](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/group__gtkmmEnums.html#gga83727a1b6fed51566dfd5c8e58890dbaa7b88e2329efd6367522358da92a3a736) or use that [version](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Box.html#a31aa59034a669239c4b99a9ced5742d6) of `pack_start`, which accepts boolean `expand` and `fill` parameters